# getting error on sending email to multiple recipients in magento 2

Tags: email, email-templates, magento2.3.3

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type
>   Error occurred when creating object:
>   Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage

```
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template')
    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
    ->setTemplateVars(
        [
            'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
        ]
    )
    ->setFrom('general')
    ->addTo(['name@gmail.com','name2@gmail.com'])
    ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
```

but on sending email to a single recipient

```
->addTo('test@gmail.com')
```

it sends without any load.

#### Magento Bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24984

Comment: I have checked the function definition at Magento 2.3.1. Code is ok. If provide full detail of log then might understand the issue

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 2.3.3 and I found this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24984

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Magento ver. 2.3.3** and I found in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24984 that it was bug, I tried to resolve it by my own.

```
private function addAddressByType(string $addressType, $email, ?string $name = null): void
{
    if (is_string($email)) {
        $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
        return;
    }
    $convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
    **$this->messageData[$addressType] = [];**
    if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
        $this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
            $this->messageData[$addressType],
            $convertedAddressArray
        );
    }
}
```

I added $this->messageData[$addressType] = []; in my function as it was not compiling code in if condition, not sure if it is right approach to do but I can send email to multiple recipients now.